# How to diff and patch new lines only

Tags: bash, shell, awk, diff, patch

I have a 2 config files(.ini) and I want to get the newly added lines from config file1 to config file2. I don't want to get modified or deleted lines.

To achieve this, I am using below commands.But they are also giving me modified/deleted lines.

```
diff -u conf2 conf1|grep -E ^\+ >temp
patch -u -o conf2 -i temp
```

Can you help in getting only newly added lines and to patch them in the exact same line number without using any third party tool. I don't want to patch modified or deleted lines either.

Here're the sample config files.

```
conf1
# app1 configuration
[app1]
username=root
ssh_port=22
http_port=8080
sd_port=8005

conf2
# app1 configuration
[app1]
username=admin
ssh_port=22
http_port=8080
```

Now, I have to patch sd_port parameter only. Not the username that got changed.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at [diff(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) you will not find anything to suppress *"changed"* or *"deleted"* lines. `diff` was designed to report ALL changes (with the ability to suppress changes in whitespace, etc..)

Comment: is there any other way to handle this ?

Comment: The only way I can think of using `diff` would be to have a copy `config file 1` that only contains new lines that you want to move to `config file 2`. If there was a way to save the file with the changes and deletions already applied, then you could `diff` the new lines only. I generally use either `diff -uNb ...` or `diff -uNw ...` to ignore changes in whitespace.

Comment: Your issue is that there is no one defined difference between a changed line and a new line. It is all dependent on your configuration file structure that only the configuration de/serializer know about. Has there been a new entry, or has there been an entry changed. Only the program using the configuration know what is an entry, what is a new entry, what is a modified entry.

Comment: This sounds to me like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problen). You're not really looking to have `diff` and `patch` merge these files. You seem to actually be wanting to do some possibly common configuration sharing. I'm guessing that there's a better way.

For instance, perhaps have a default configuration file, and allow overrides in another. If we knew more about your actual end goal, we could perhaps recommend some more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with awk. With

/* diff.awk */

```
BEGIN {FS="="}
FILENAME==ARGV[1] && $1 !~ /^[#\[]/ {
    a[$1]=$2
} 
FILENAME==ARGV[2] {
    b[$1]=$2
}
END {
    for(i in b) {
        for(j in a) {
            if(!b[j]) {
                c[j]=a[j]
            }
        }
        c[i]=b[i]
    }
    for(k in c) {
        print k"="c[k]
    }
}
```

Running

```
awk -f diff.awk conf1 conf2
```

should give you

```
sd_port=8005
ssh_port=22
http_port=8080
username=admin
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your input. It is doing the difference without order and from both files. Also, can we ignore the lines starting with "#" and "[" from comparison.
what we need is only newly added lines of conf1 file into conf2 in an ordered manner.

Comment: Below 2 commands does the job. But, looking for alternatives without git client installed.

    `git diff --diff-filter=a conf2 conf1|grep -E ^\+ >temp`  
    `patch -o conf2 -i temp`

Comment: Although the solution you found might work for you since you have the git commit history to play with but it can't be used in more general situations. Also I am not seeing order extremely important for config files and sorting them only makes cosmetics differences. For skipping lines starting with '#' and '[' please see the updated answer.

Comment: Would like to add a point on your comment. Neither I have git commit history nor git is my source control here. Seems like, it works on any files.

Comment: Your are right, thanks for sharing this interesting solution.

Comment: @ Rico Chen 
Appreciate your prompt response. only 2 gaps I could see.  
1. Order is very important for us.  
2. for empty lines it is adding "=", this is minor and can be handled by removing lines starting with =.

Comment: Also keep in mind my solution might not work any more due to your `[app]` addition to your examples after your original post. The awk solution I gave assume that you have flat (simple) config file structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196754/discussion-between-rico-chen-and-ras-dama).